# How to take the sum of elements from a for loop?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class objectDetails {

    double w, t, res, amt;

    String ob;

    void getDetails(int n) {
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);

        int limit = n;

        System.out.println("Enter Object Details\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            System.out.println("Name of appliance:\n");

            ob = get.next();

            System.out.println("Enter the amount of watts per hour:\n");

            w = get.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Enter the amount of time in hours used:\n");

            t = get.nextDouble();

            res = (w * t) / 1000;

            amt = (res * 4.2);

            System.out.println("The amount in ruppes payable=" + amt);

        }
    }
}
```

i want the sum of amt from all the iterations in the loop. Add all the amt and display the total amount payable. im new to coding trying to self learn. thank you

Comment: You say you're trying to self-learn, but that doesn't come by copying and pasting our solutions.  It comes by trying it yourself, and asking *specific* questions if/when you fail.

Comment: Learn to format your code first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop,

```
double total = 0;
```

and then *in* the loop (after you calculate the amount)

```
total += amt;
```

and finally **after** the loop, something like

```
System.out.printf("The total is %.2f%n", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign one global variable and store the value in that variable and at last print the value of that global variable.
thats all